# Bootstrap Autocomplite plugins

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I'm trying to find some Bootstrap Autocomplete plugin, to make autocomplete by cities. 
For exemple I have such arrow:

```
 {
   ['Alabama','USA'],
   ['Alaska','USA'],
   ['London','UK'],
   ['Kiev','Ukraine'],
 }
```

and make searching by first letters of city string(country don't take).
The most nice plugin that I've found: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

But in it searching goes by all entered symbols.

So:

- i'm looking for autocomplete by name of city by first symbols, and shows with country;
- if I wrote "Al", select box must show:

**Al**abama, USA

**Al**aska, USA

with highlited "Al".

---

Maybe will be good idea change arrow to strings like:

```
['Alabama, USA', 'Alaska, USA', 'London, UK','Kiev, Ukraine']
```

?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have been using MagicSuggest pluggin since years. Very easy to manage, it will provides you auto suggestion and auto select too.Plenty of options are available.

Please have a look at [MagicSuggest demo](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/examples.html).

For documentation  [see here](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html)

Have a look on [sample codes](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/tutorial.html)

To download please go to [GitHub](https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest)

As per my understanding it might help you. If you found any difficulties feel free to ask.

Thanks

Comment: Almost, but not quite what I was looking for.
I want to see list like in google maps, when you enter some direction.
But thank you, it's a nice plugin, maybe i'll us it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is select2 : https://select2.github.io/

You can check out the example here : https://select2.github.io/examples.html

You may also want to arrange your array to something like this:

```
{
  ['Alabama, USA'],
  ['Alaska, USA'],
  ['London, UK']
}
```